# Output the_title() inside the_content()

Tags: the-content

I'm sure this isn't possible but thought I'd ask.

I have a testimonials section, the html of each testimonial is like so

```
    <p>
      the testimonal here blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah
      <em>Name of person</em>
    </p>
```

Now in WP I have the testimonials as a Custom post type. The Name of person is the title and the testimonial is the content.

Can I output the testimonial post so it's like the html.

So it would be the_title inside a 'em' which is inside the 'p' of the_content.

I know I could add the name inside the content in wordpress and then make that italic but I know the client wouldn't like doing this.

Comment: Can you just repeat the title After the content and style it however with css?

Comment: I don't think I understand. If I use the_content() then the_title() I get a p tag containing the content and a separate p tag containing the title. I can't move the title inside the content p tag with css.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve that with a [filter on `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content):

```
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( 'testimonial' == $post->post_type )
        $content .= ' <em>' . $post->post_title . '</em>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just repeat the_title() after the_content(), as @Howdy_McGee suggested, or use [the_content filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content). For example:

```
//Make your conditional to check if the current post is of your custom post type
//Maybe remove wpautop to not have nested <p> elements?
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
add_filter( 'the_content','filter_function_name');
function filter_function_name($content){
   $content = '<p>'.$content.'<em>'.get_the_title().'</em></p>';
   return $content;
}
```

Just a note: don't use `the_title()` inside the filter because `the_title()` will echo the title and is not suitable here. Use `get_the_title();` instead.

Comment: You're not modifying the content really in the filter, why not use `echo get_the_content().get_the_title()` in The Loop instead?

Comment: That is why I started the answer with "You can just repeat the_title() after the_content()" but I thought is interesting teach how to modify the content, just in case he needs to make some more changes.

Comment: Doesn't meet the requirements in the question: "So it would be the_title inside a 'em' which is inside the 'p' of the_content". A minor edit would make it match though.

Answer (score 1):

[Build a shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API):

```
function echo_title_in_post( $atts, $content = null ) {
  return '<em>'.get_the_title().'</em>';
}
add_shortcode('the_title','echo_title_in_post');
```

Then add `[the_title/]` to your post body wherever you want the title to appear.

Comment: The shortcode option is fine but if Simon has a custom post type and he wants the same structure in all post of that type, adding the shortcode to all posts is not the best solution. I think.

Comment: I am not sure the question is clear enough to allow for a distinct solution. That is why there are several answers. I am afraid that the OP is asking for something that requires `regex` on the post content, but hopefully someone's solution will work without that.

Answer (score 0):

I feel CSS is best suited for this personally.

**Inside Your Loop**

```
the_content();
the_title('<span class="title">', '</span>');
```

**CSS** - Here you can move it or style it however you want:

```
.title{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: the other answers don't preclude a css component, but they also don't require editing a template file accomplish